# Visual Studio: Meaning of cs8300 "merge conflict marker encountered"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am debugging a program, and see compilation error

> cs8300 "merge conflict marker encountered"

What does this mean? Is there any Microsoft Documentation for this? We are working with Git Source control, and trying to compile Net Core program.

Comment: why was this downvoted? trying to learn and fix, don't see documentation online

Comment: Looking at the vote it was cast due to _someone else_ thinking it is off-topic. However I believe this is on-topic because it's a tool closely related to development.

Comment: I guess you got a file name and a line number - have a look at that with an editor/ide. You might see something like `<<<` or `>>>` or other kinds of markers left probably from an incomplete merge/rebase. For better feedback you should include more info, especially relevant one (not flooding use with all source files but keeping it to a minimum working/reproducing example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is if you have being doing a merge or a pull from either another branch or from the remote source control, there was a conflict i.e. someone has changed the same line as you have. This begins a "conflict resolution" in Visual Studio asking you to choose which lines you want.

However I suspect you have attempted to build the project without completing the conflict resolution.

The conflict will add little bits of text to your files indicating to Git where the conflicts are, if you open the files in a plain text editor like notepad you will see them.

For further background information here is the documentation regarding resolving merge conflicts in Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

Here is a screen shot taken from that documentation which you will *likely* see in Visual Studio.

[image: Merge conflict screen shot]

Comment: thanks, this helps, I completed the merge conflicts, accepted, but have not committed, and messages show, will research more,

Comment: @JohnAllen27 No worries hope I can help, that's interesting I would of thought completing would of been it. Perhaps see if you can see the files in a plain text editor to see what the trouble could be. Alternatively the Visual Studio feature related to the error http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features/ConflictMarkerResolution/CSharpResolveConflictMarkerCodeFixProvider.cs hints that there may be an autofix for it, perhaps try pressing ctrl+. on the area of the code with the problem (if it indicates what the line is in the errors tab).

Comment: It may also help if you can provide a screen shot of the error message in visual studio and/or the area of the code with the problem (redact anything sensitive if you need to), as it may help us diagnose it.

Comment: This is what appears to be detecting the issue: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/ConflictMarkerResolution/AbstractConflictMarkerCodeFixProvider.cs,a62ffd9967703cc3 so perhaps searching your code for >> or << maybe a quick way of spotting the problem.